# Парсинг fetch/xhr запросов пайтон

Tags: python, selenium, requests, xhr

Всем привет, при парсинге сайта https://akniga.org/ впервые столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия ссылки на медиаконтент.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Беглый гугл подсказал смотреть на код страницы, обнаружил что данные подгружаются с сервера в запросах вкладки сеть. необходимо получить ссылку этого файла (pl.m3u8) с его помощью можно загрузить всю аудиодорожку и сохранить её с помощью ffmpeg на пк.

Буду благодарен любой помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути говоря вы работаете не с медиафайлом, который привыкли видеть, а с потоковым форматом, иначе говоря медиапотоком.

Уверен, что есть какие-то библиотеки, которые автоматизируют этот процесс, я же покажу просто "на пальцах", как это работает, так как сам особо с этим не работал, но только что для себя проанализировал.

На сайте вы можете найти `HLS (M3U8)` файл, который содержит в себе метаданные об имеющихся вложенных потоках. Чтобы скачать его, вам достаточно перейти по ссылке в браузере, ее можно увидеть прямо в консоли разработчика:

`https://h7.akniga.club/b/86477/pl.m3u8?res=your_key&expires=1704007036`

На выходе вы получите файл с вложенными сегментами. Вот примерный вид этого файла:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://h11.akniga.club/datakeys/enc.key",IV=your IV
#EXTINF:30.016000,
seq0.ts
#EXTINF:29.994667,
seq1.ts
#EXTINF:29.994667,
seq2.ts
#EXTINF:29.994667,
seq3.ts
#EXTINF:30.016000,
seq4.ts
#EXTINF:29.994667,
seq5.ts
...
```

По сути говоря поток в данном случае зашифрован методом `AES-128`.

Ключ вы получаете по ссылке `https://h11.akniga.club/datakeys/enc.key` а вектор инициализации `(IV)` уже явно прописан в файле. Явно прописывать в файле ничего не нужно, так как ffmpeg сам получит этот ключ и будет декодировать сегменты, но путь к нему можно прописать по надобности и вручную.

Затем вам нужно скачать файлы с расширением `*.ts`. Исходя из файла `.M3U8` в моем примере - их было 94, у вас может быть другое значение.
Но так как вы говорите, что `ffmpeg` сам выгружает, тогда этот этап можно пропустить.

Тем не менее простенький пример, как быстро выгрузить эти файлы:

```
import requests


count_of_ts = 94

for count in range(0, count_of_ts + 1):
    print(f'Downloading segment {count}')
    response = requests.get(f'https://h7.akniga.club/b/86477/seq{count}.ts')
    with open(f'seg{count}.ts', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

Вы можете автоматизировать этот процесс и улучшить код, так как это не более чем простой наглядный пример, чтобы показать, как быстро скачать все файлы вручную - моя задача донести вам всего лишь концепт работы. Уверен, что есть лучший способ, или может даже `ffmpeg` сам скачивает - это стоит вам исследовать.

После этого используйте `ffmpeg` чтобы собрать медиапоток в медиафайл.

Я использовал `Windows`, и я не часто работал с `ffmpeg`, поэтому в `mp3` не удалось конвертировать, но в `mp4` у меня сегменты были собраны в медиафайл. Если не ошибаюсь, то должны быть какие-то дополнительные драйвера, чтобы можно было перекодировать в `mp3`. В любом случае `mp4` можно конвертировать в `mp3` через какой-то другой сервис.

Так как я просто показываю пример, как быстро собрать этот медиафайл, то использовал вот такую команду:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto" -allowed_extensions ALL -i book.m3u8 -acodec copy output_test.mp4
```

Вам же рекомендую использовать более тонкую настройку `ffmpeg` и разобраться что означает каждый флаг для него.

Обновление:

Я не писал в комментариях, что использование `seleniumwire` - это хорошее решение. Лучше того, я написал что лучшее решение, так это сделать на обычных реквестах, нужно только разобраться, как генерируется `res` для `XHR`-запроса, то есть исследовать вам `js`-код, но все зависит от ваших предпочтений.

Тем не менее, вариант с `seleniumwire` рабочий. Как и написал, вам нужно установить небольшую задержку, потому что ответ от `XHR` приходит не сразу. Чтобы снизить нагрузку на процессор, то можно открыть `selenium` в `headless` режиме - это, по сути говоря, скроет графический интерфейс браузера. Вот самый простой пример на первой попавшейся книге:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://akniga.org/lansdeyl-dzho-r-dzhentlmenskiy-otel')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

find_url = None
for request in driver.requests:
    if '.m3u8' in request.url:
        find_url = request.url
        print(find_url)
        break

driver.quit()
# дальнейшая работа с ссылкой
```

Вариант не идеален, так как установлено неявное ожидание для `selenium` с вероятностным, а не точным поиском ссылки, тем не менее для демонстрационных целей код работает, вам нужно только улучшить его.

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо вам за развернутый ответ к сожалению со всем этим я уже разобрался, но мне так же не понятно как спарсить саму ссылку на файл pl.m3u8. Если я беру её в ручную то все работает напрямую из ffmpeg (даже нет смысла как оказалось скачивать .ts файлы) вот пример subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', "-protocol_whitelist", 'file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto', "-i", "https://h6.akniga.club/b/73253/pl.m3u8?res=5P2DuWwxqwrqY6HL913FQA&expires=1705650792", "-codec", "copy", "output_all.mp4"]). Мне же необходимо спарсить именно ссылку на этот файл.

Comment: Но я не понимаю как это сделать библиотека seleniumwire может мне в этом помочь но я пока не смог с ней разобраться. Спасибо еще раз вам за развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @Zoombi_89_adm только что попробовал seleniumwire, и я смог получить эту ссылку. После `driver.get('ссылка на вашу аудиокнигу')` поставьте небольшую задержку, скажем в несколько секунд - это время нужно для обработки `XHR`-запроса, после чего сделайте проверку `if '.m3u8' in request.url:` (когда итерируетесь по `driver.requests`) то значит это ваша ссылка, и дальше уже можете проводить манипуляции с ней. Этого в принципе должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Но более элегантное решение конечно было бы, если вручную собрать ссылку. Найти id книги не проблема (которая идет после `/b/`), он находится в теге `data-bid` на странице. Проблема - найти res, как он генерируется. Эта логика там есть, и это делает javascript, нюанс только в том - что пока непонятно, какой из участков кода его генерирует. В любом случае то что я описал выше - будет работать:) Но если хотите решить эту задачу на отлично и без seleniumwire чисто на реквестах, то можно конечно и поисследовать js-код, но тут уже зависит от ваших предпочтений.

Comment: Уважаемый как вам удалось вытащить ссылку с использованием driver.get('url')?? Я смог сделать только так - driver.request_interceptor = intercept_request; driver.get(url);requests_list.append(request.url); for i in requests_list: if 'pl.m3u8' in i: print(i); driver.quit(); break При этом загрузка процессора вырастает до 50% секунд на 5 я сомневаюсь что это правильное решение для такой не сложной операции. К сожалению у меня не получилось поймать ссылку вашим методом. В любом случае вы натолкнули меня на решение хоть и не самое оптимизированное. В любом случае спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Zoombi_89_adm дополнил ответ

Comment: Если исключить ожидание происходит тоже самое, мой вариант работает так же. Процессор грузить так же зато у вас это происходит в фоне. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста еще как сделать это одной командой. subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', "-protocol_whitelist", 'file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto', "-i", "https://h6.akniga.club/b/73253/pl.m3u8?res=5P2DuWwxqwrqY6HL913FQA&expires=1705650792", "-codec", "copy", "output_all.mp4"])  # Рабочий вариант с url; subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'output_all.mp4', '-c:a', 'copy', 'aac.aac', "output__all.mp3"])

Comment: def save_ffmpeg_file(path_folder, path_save):
    subprocess.run(['ffmpeg',
                    '-protocol_whitelist',
                    "file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto",
                    '-allowed_extensions',
                    'ALL',
                    '-i',
                    path_folder + '\\' + 'pl.m3u8',
                    '-vcodec',
                    'copy',
                    path_save])  # Рабочий мп3

Comment: def save_ffmpeg_url(url, path_save):
    subprocess.run(['ffmpeg',
                    '-protocol_whitelist',
                    "file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto",
                    '-allowed_extensions',
                    'ALL',
                    '-i',
                    url,
                    # Меняем на ссылку
                    '-vcodec',
                    'copy',
                    path_save])  # Рабочий мп3 с url